# Does orphanRemoval = true imply cascade delete

Tags: jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

Consider a one-to-many relationship. Does orphanRemoval = true necessary imply delete cascade.

```
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH},  orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Set<Child> child;
```

Whats happening if I remove a parent with existing child without prior clearing the collection?

FK constraint failure or child removal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the specs.

> Associations that are specified as OneToOne or OneToMany support use
>   of the orphanRemoval option.
>
> The following behaviors apply when orphanRemoval is in effect:
>
> - If an entity that is the target of therelationship is removed from the relationship (by setting the relationship to null or removing the
>     entity from the relationship collection), the remove operation will be
>     applied to the entity being orphaned. The remove operation is applied
>     at the time of the flush operation. The orphanRemoval functionality is
>     intended for entities that are privately "owned" by their parent
>     entity. Portable applications must otherwise not depend upon a
>     specific order of removal, and must not reassign an entity that has
>     been orphaned to another relationship or otherwise attempt to persist
>     it. If the entity being orphaned is a detached, new, or removed
>     entity, the semantics of orphanRemoval do not apply.
> - If the remove operation is applied to a managed source entity, the remove operation will be cascaded to the relationship target in
>     accordance with the rules of section 3.2.3, (and hence it is not
>     necessary to specify cascade=REMOVE for the relationship)[20].

It means if you remove the parent of the relationship the cascade REMOVE will apply to the objects in the collection that are the target of the relationship, so answer is yes, orphanRemoval imply Cascade.REMOVE if does not matter you set to null the collection or not. It means orphans are not allowed in the model for that relationship.